# Select a div, if you click on the div, or a child element

Tags: jquery, element

I'm trying to select a parent class when I click on the child element using `event.target`. I check if it's the `div`, by seeing what class it has, and if its not the `div`, I find the `div` selecting it from the child element, but then it doesn't seem to work, and it wont `hide()`.

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    elem_id = $('#'+e.target.id);
    if(!elem_id.hasClass('mail_schedule_dropdown')) elem_id = $('#'+e.target.id).find('.mail_schedule_dropdown');
    elem_id.hide();
});

<div id="parent" class="mail_schedule_dropdown"><span>child</span></div>
```

How do I select the parent element if I click on `div`? This is not working:

```
elem_id = $('#'+e.target.id).find('.mail_schedule_dropdown');
```

Why doesnt that work?

Comment: do you want to select the parent element when clicking on the child element?

Comment: yes correct, select parent element when clicking on child element, but at the same time, if the parent element is clicked on, and not the child element, then also select the parent element

Comment: Is this what you're trying to accomplish? https://jsfiddle.net/ab1cfdg8/ I'm not sure that I follow what you need...

Comment: @Source clicking on your parent div `.mail_schedule_dropdown`, the div itself hides. Do you also want to hide this div by clicking on child `<span>` or on `document` click?

Comment: Don't Panic is right for the fact that you are certainly doing it all in wrong direction. `mail_schedule_dropdown` is your parent element's class and you are still finding this element. In fact you should look for its ancestor element. Also `elem_id` is not an element's ID, in fact it is a jQuery object.

Comment: @Source does my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

You're just looking in the wrong direction.  From [the jQuery docs for `.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/):

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

In your code, if the clicked element does not have your class, you are searching its *descendants* for the parent.  But in fact in that case it must be the child that was clicked, so you need to search its *ancestors*.

There are a few ways to do that, but [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) is maybe most appropriate:

```
elem_id = $('#'+e.target.id).closest('.mail_schedule_dropdown');
```

**Side Note**

The variable names in the code threw me a little.  `elem_id` is not an ID at all, it is an actual jQuery object representing an element.  It seems trivial, but when juggling IDs as strings, elements and selectors, and once your code gets more complex that's enough to cause errors down the line - at least it's happened to me!  Here's my tweaked-for-clarity-version:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    // Using '$' makes it clear that this represents a jQuery object;
    // The variable name makes it clear exactly what it is
    var $clicked = $('#'+e.target.id);
    if (!$clicked.hasClass('mail_schedule_dropdown')) {
        $clicked = $clicked.find('.mail_schedule_dropdown');
    }
    $clicked.hide();
});
```